# Converting from js to ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to have protected routes using role based Authorization in React and typescript. I am little new to it and facing below issue

I get error when I use below in my Login.tsx

```
const {setAuth} = useAuth();
```

> Property 'setAuth' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)

I have created below files useAuth.ts

```
import {useContext} from "react";
import AuthContext from "../context/AuthProvider";

const useAuth = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export default useAuth;
```

AuthProvider.tsx

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState({});

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AuthContext;
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I was missing to initialize it. Did below change and it works.

```
const AuthContext = createContext(null);
```